# Can't connect to Pi Zero over USB

Tags: usb, ssh, pi-zero

I followed the guides [here](https://desertbot.io/blog/ssh-into-pi-zero-over-usb) and [here](https://desertbot.io/blog/headless-pi-zero-ssh-access-over-usb-windows), both times freshly flashing Raspbian Buster Lite to the SD and modifying the config files. I leave the Pi around 3 minutes to boot, with it connected to my PC's USB port, anfd the light is solidly on. However, I keep getting `ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi.local: No such host is known.`. Bonjour is definitely installed on my Windows machine. Is there a way to get it working?

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by switching off my VPN and using a different USB cable; either one of these could have fixed it. I hope this solves any issues others may have.

Comment: Yes, "swapping cables" is a good troubleshooting technique.  I am  a poor hobbyist and therefore prefer to buy the cheapest USB cables I could find.  Then I found USB cables can not be too long, especially when using Win32DiskImage to make Rpi OS images. USB cables, even not long, but with very thin cables, when used to give 5V power, sometimes also cause trouble.  I find those cables, though cheap but with "beads", or "chokes" at both ends are useful when you need to use long cables in noisy environments, and copying big images.